# How to name variables that clash with functions?

Tags: python, coding-standards, naming, functions, variables

As an example, in Python I have a `lowest_prime_factor` function which does it exactly what it says it does. Then, in another function, I need to call this function and store it. In another language where variables and functions can share names then I would simply do `lowest_prime_factor = lowest_prime_factor(n)`. In Python though, this actually redefines `lowest_prime_factor` such that it's no longer a function at all (which is problematic as I need to call it again several lines later).

So I need to name the variable something else - but what else is there that intuitively says "this variable holds the lowest prime factor"? This is where different casing could come in handy, i.e. starting functions with uppercase letters, but it seems Python more than any other language has a very "fixed"/well defined naming convention that means I probably shouldn't do this.

Comment: Using the get prefix for functions is common in other languages but it seems your variable is local to the other function so it would be ok to name that lpf. You just use the result (lpf) in some calculation to produce some other result right? And you want to buffer the lowest prime factor only to prevent it from being calculated more than once, right?

Comment: If the variable is of limited scope (e.g. used only within one function), then you should use a short name for that object. e.g. `factor = get_lowest_prime_factor(n)`. If it is of larger scope, use a sufficiently descriptive name that reminds you of how you're going to be using that object, e.g. `encryption_factor = get_lowest_prime_factor(n)`.

Comment: "`lowest_prime_factor = ...`". Lowest prime factor is dependent in a value. Having a variable called this is meaningless. At the very least, you variable should be called `lowest_prime_factor_of_n`, but it would likely be better to give `n` a proper name too. Though without code, it's difficult to guess what `n` is.

Answer (score 6):

One very commonly used coding style (and one which is largely language independent) is that **variables are nouns and functions are verbs**, as it's the functions which actually do stuff. As such, this makes it very unlikely that variable and function names clash.

Why is this a good idea? Function names which are verbs are much more self-documenting: it isn't instantly obvious what `lowest_prime_factor(n)` does - it probably calculates the lowest prime factor of `n`, but maybe it doesn't, or maybe it prints out the factor as well. If it's called `get_lowest_prime_factor`, everything is a lot clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here are some ideas.

- Rename the function to `get_lowest_prime_factor`, `find_lowest_prime_factor`, or `calculate_lowest_prime_factor`.
- Arbitrarily rename one or the other to `smallest_prime_factor`. (On the other hand, using the words "lowest" and "smallest" for the same thing is inconsistent, and consistency is good.)
- Rename the variable to something longer, like `the_lowest_prime_factor`, or perhaps `lowest_prime_factor_n`.
- Rename the variable to something shorter, like `factor` or `lpf`.
- Determine why this variable needs to contain the lowest prime factor, and name it after that reason. Perhaps you're using this variable in order to divide the input into equal pieces; in that case, call it `piece_size`.
- If you're only using the variable in one place, just get rid of the variable and use the function call `lowest_prime_factor(n)` directly.